# El Else If no funciona

Tags: java, array, string, jframe, random

Tengo un problema que me lleva persiguiendo desde esta tarde.
Estoy haciendo un blackjack con un array de strings y numero random.
El array toma el numero random y aplica la imagen que quiero que aparezca, por ejemplo: El numero random saca la carta 2, aparece la carta 2 en la pantalla. ¿Cual es el problema? Que el If else lo utilizo para darle u nvalor a esa carta, en este caso la carta 2 tiene un valor de 2 puntos. A continuación dejare el codigo.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int puntaje1 = 0, puntaje2 = 0, fichas = 500, apuesta = 0;
String[] cartasdispo = new String[52];
int controlaturnosp1 = 5;
String res;

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        cartasdispo[i + 1] = "/imagenes/carta" + (i + 1) + ".png";
    }
    for (int i = 10; i < 18; i++) {
        cartasdispo[i + 1] = "/imagenes/carta" + (i + 1) + "_1.png";
    }
    for (int i = 19; i < 27; i++) {
        cartasdispo[i + 1] = "/imagenes/carta" + (i + 1) + "_2.png";
    }
    for (int i = 28; i < 36; i++) {
        cartasdispo[i + 1] = "/imagenes/carta" + (i + 1) + "_3.png";
    }
    for (int i = 41; i < 43; i++) {
        cartasdispo[i + 1] = "/imagenes/carta" + (i + 1) + "_1.png";
    }
    for (int i = 44; i < 46; i++) {
        cartasdispo[i + 1] = "/imagenes/carta" + (i + 1) + "_2.png";
    }
    for (int i = 41; i < 43; i++) {
        cartasdispo[i + 1] = "/imagenes/carta" + (i + 1) + "_3.png";
    }
    for (int i = 47; i < 49; i++) {
        cartasdispo[i + 1] = "/imagenes/carta" + (i + 1) + "_1.png";
    }

Carta.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(cartasdispo[1])));
            controlaturnosp1--;
            if (cartasdispo[1].equals("carta1.png") || cartasdispo[10].equals("carta1_1.png")
                    || cartasdispo[19].equals("carta1_2.png") || cartasdispo[29].equals("carta1_3.png")) {
                puntaje1 += 2;
                casillajugador.setText("" + puntaje1);
            }
```

### Quiero recalcar que tengo las siguientes limitaciones:
Contenidos que debe tener:
Arrays.
Selectores.
Condicionales anidados.
conectivos lógicos.

Aparece un nuevo error: Reaparece el error exception pero de una forma extraña.
EL int random anteriormente mencionado en el arreglo de arrays-strings, pero sucede algo extraño.
El If else funciona gracias a Pablo pero solo me toma la primera parte del if else, es decir:

```
                if (cartasdispo[1].endsWith("carta1.png") || cartasdispo[10].endsWith("carta1_1.png")
                    || cartasdispo[19].endsWith("carta1_2.png") || cartasdispo[29].endsWith("carta1_3.png")) {
                puntaje1 += 2;
                casillajugador.setText("" + puntaje1);
            }
```

En otros if else como:

```
else if (cartasdispo[2].endsWith("carta2.png") || cartasdispo[11].endsWith("carta2_1.png")
                    || cartasdispo[20].endsWith("carta2_2.png") || cartasdispo[30].endsWith("carta2_3.png")) {
                puntaje1 += 3;
                casillajugador.setText("" + puntaje1);
            }
```

No funciona, y la parte mas extraña es cuando el seticon+arreglo da error UNICAMENTE estando activo el If else.

```
Carta.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(cartasdispo[arreglo])));
```

Si a ese seticon+arreglo le pongo en vez de arreglo el numero 3, toma la imagen 3 pero el puntaje da 2 ¿Por que da 2 si puse que el numero 3 de 3 puntos?.

Segun netbeans el error es el siguiente:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
at juego.pedircartaMouseClicked(juego.java:522)
at juego.access$000(juego.java:6)
at juego$1.mouseClicked(juego.java:59)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6536)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4534)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

*En la linea 522 esta el carta.seticon+arreglo*

Comment: Cuál viene siendo el error o lo que te está persiguiendo desde la tarde?

Comment: ¿Obtienes algún error?

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at juego.pedircartaMouseClicked(juego.java:518).
Este error, justo cuando comienza el if else, si es que te referis a ese error

Comment: @DavidPeña el error viene desde el if else, no pasa ni a true ni a false, da error, tal vez sea un error estupido mio jaja
Pero recien estoy empezando a programar y cuesta un poco..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu código veo dos problemas:

Si revisas bien la construcción de los diferentes `for`, notarás que no le estás asignando valores a las posiciones del arreglo que utilizas en el `if`

El primer `for` se ejecuta hasta que el valor de `i` sea menor que `9`, es decir del `0 al 8` y con la suma `[i+1]` estás asignando las posiciones del `1 al 9` en el arreglo.

```
//       del 0 al 8    
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

     // asignas del 1 al 9
     cartasdispo[i + 1]
```

El segundo `for` va del `10 al 17` y como sumas `[i+1]` asignas las posiciones del `11 al 18` dejando la posición `10` sin asignar.

De manera similar ocurre con el resto de los `for`

Una vez que resuelvas esa parte dejará de ocurrir la `Exception` pero te darás cuenta que nunca se cumple la condición del `if` y es porque los valores que asignas a las diferentes posiciones del arreglo comienzan por el texto `/imagenes/` y ese texto no lo inluyes en las comparaciones.

Mi sugerencia es que utilices el método [`String.endsWith()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String)) de la siguiente manera (omito parte de tu código para mantener el foco en el área de interes):

```
...
if (cartasdispo[1].endsWith("carta1.png") || 
    cartasdispo[10].endsWith("carta1_1.png") ||
    cartasdispo[19].endsWith("carta1_2.png") || 
    cartasdispo[29].endsWith("carta1_3.png")) {
            puntaje1 += 2;
            casillajugador.setText("" + puntaje1);
        }
```

**Actualización**

Con la nueva información que aportas en la actualización de la pregunta y en los comentarios, se hace evidente un error adicional a los ya documentados.

De acuerdo con lo que mencionas, hay una variable llamada `arreglo` que contiene el valor random generado. Es una información muy importante que no está en el código que publicaste originalmente.

> `int arreglo = rnd.nextInt(52) + 1;`

La razón por la que siempre asigna 2 al puntaje es porque la primera condición que se cumple es `cartasdispo[1].endsWith("carta1.png")`, es decir, es completamente cierto que la posición 1 del arreglo siempre termina en `carta1.png`.

Para corregir esto, debes modificar todas las condiciones y cambiar el número fijo por `arreglo` como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
...
if (cartasdispo[arreglo].endsWith("carta1.png") || 
    cartasdispo[arreglo].endsWith("carta1_1.png") ||
    cartasdispo[arreglo].endsWith("carta1_2.png") || 
    cartasdispo[arreglo].endsWith("carta1_3.png")) {
            puntaje1 += 2;
            casillajugador.setText("" + puntaje1);
        }
```

De esta manera ahora todo tiene más sentido.

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS :'D desconocia por cmpleto el "endswith" y el error del for ni me habia percatado!

Comment: Hay algo que no entiendo, me aparece Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
Pero me fijo que error marca y me marca la linea 522 la cual esta el arreglo, pero el arreglo ¿funciona?.
Pero al mismo tiempo lo marca como que no funciona

Comment: @Makuro, por favor edita tu pregunta para agregar el código ya corregido de la pregunta original y por favor señala la línea que te produce el nuevo error.

Comment: Disculpe, soy nuevo en stackoverflow y estoy un poco perdido, ahi publique el nuevo error! Si no se entiende algo digame

Comment: @Makuro, de la nueva explicación que das en la actualización de tu pregunta infiero que la variable `arreglo` contiene el valor generado por el random ¿esto es así?.

Comment: Claro, lo puse como:
Random rnd = new Random();
int arreglo = rnd.nextInt(52) + 1;

Comment: @Makuro, acabo de actualizar mi respuesta con información acerca del nuevo error que se te está presentando.